# Bezier spline evaluation correctness

Tags: qt, math, evaluation, bezier, spline

What is the best/most correct way of evaluating spline curves at arbitrary points?

I have plotted my evaluation results and compared them to what I get from using a UI library and found out my results are off.

I'm using the cubic formula for the central segments, and quadratic for the first & last segments of the curve.

[image: http://www.it.hiof.no/~borres/j3d/jlatexmath/BezierFunction0small.png]

I think that the reason I'm having this issue is because in its evaluation the X coordinate changes (shifts) and I'm currently evaluating it at constant stepped coordinates which causes some differences between the input x and the output one (which I am currently ignoring)

I can provide code if needed. (I'm using Qt as a way to check for correctness in case it helps)

Comment: "the reason I'm having this issue" What issue?? // "I can provide code if needed" Of course it's needed! // "I'm using Qt as a way to check..." Only Qt? What's the base language?

Comment: @DYangu thanks for replying. It really is more of a mathematical issue than a programmatic one, that's why I didn't include code nor specified the language in the first place. I am more than happy to provide it though.

I have now confirmed that the issue comes from doing a "constant stepped evaluation" of the curve without taking into account the derivatives of the curve. If I were to take into account the arc length it would probably work but can't quite work out how to do that. I will update the post if I do. cheers.

Comment: Yes, please. Provide some code and your error output. I'm still not clear what your error is.

Comment: the best way? use their mathematical description, which you already clearly have. [What is the actual programming problem that you need help with?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *It really is more of a mathematical issue than a programmatic one*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a combination of maths and programming.

I have since expanded my knowledge on the specific type of curves that I was implementing and I can now explain better what I was trying to achieve and what my issue was. Apologies for any confusion this may have caused.

I was implementing an FCurve and needed to be able to "evaluate" it at arbitrary input values. FCurves are splines that represent a function (that is for any given input they return a single unique output)

When evaluating my older spline implementation I was getting incorrect evaluation results because my evaluation code did not take into account the curves arc-length aside from the fact that FCurves are slightly more restrictive.

The way I am currently using to get exact evaluation values has been to fill up a set of "segment samples" with differing "t" along the segment, and then iterating through it to find the closest matches and doing a linear interpolation between them. I will later on go back to it and try to find a smart way of getting how many samples are really required to evaluate the segment with a minimum error but for now this works very nicely.

All of this was happening because when applying the above formula (cubic bezier) it's fairly common to get different "x" values from the input "x" and "t".

Here is the bit of code that I ended up with when evaluating it:

```
    const uint32_t sampleCount = 20;
    Vec2 samples[sampleCount];
    fillSegmentSamples(x, &samples[0], sampleCount);

    uint32_t best = 0;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    {
        if(samples[i].x > x)
            break;

        best = i;
    }

    uint32_t nxt = best + 1;
    if(nxt >= sampleCount)
    {
        best--;
        nxt--;
    }

    float t = (x - samples[best].x) / (samples[nxt].x - samples[best].x);

    y = lerp(samples[best].y, samples[nxt].y, t);
```

Before, I was running the equivalent of the following, which was wrong as it does not do any kind of compensation for x-axis shifting. (note that in this case the "t" gets extracted from "x")

```
Vec2 samples[1];
fillSegmentSamples(x, &samples[0], 1);
y = samples[0].y;
```

These are two questions/answers that helped me understand what was going wrong:

- http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/curves-and-splines/#a-draw-bezier
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5373/moving-ships-between-two-planets-along-a-bezier-missing-some-equations-for-acce/5427#5427

they aren't regarding fcurves specifically but the arc-length gave me the hint to fix this up.

Cheers!